# Checking if data is immutable

Tags: javascript

What is the quickest and cleanest way to test if a `var` holds immutable data (i.e. is `string`, `number`, `boolean`, `null`, `undefined`)?

E.g. When `var test` is mutable, the following is legal:

```
var test = {}; 
//the next 2 lines work because `test` has mutable data
test.someFun = function () { alert(this); };
test.someFun();
```

but when `var test` is immutable, it's illegal:

```
var test = "string"; 
//the next 2 lines are invalid, as `test` is a primitive
test.someFun = function () { alert(this); };
test.someFun();
```

Comment: In case anyone wants to compare the below solutions performance in their given browser: http://jsperf.com/checking-mutability/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var test = {};
if(test instanceof Object){
  test.someFun = function () { alert(this); };
  test.someFun(); 
}
```

jball pointed out the following:

> For the instanceof check to work, the
>   left-hand side object should be from
>   the same scope as the right-hand side
>   object. This is because even the
>   common JavaScript objects have
>   different copies in different scopes,
>   i.e. `window1.String !== window2.String.`
>   (Quote [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/Instanceof_Operator#instanceof_and_multiple_scopes_%28e.g._frames_or_windows%29))

Seems a valid point to me. So if you want to do this check across different scopes you will need to use the workaround:

```
var test = {};
if(test && (typeof test == 'object' || typeof test == 'function')){
  test.someFun = function () { alert(this); };
  test.someFun(); 
}
```

I would try to avoid the use of iframes though.
The null check is needed because `typeof(null)` is equal to `'object'`.

### EDIT:

box9 and jball did some [performance testing](http://jsperf.com/checking-mutability/4) on all the methods proposed (+1 for that). I used Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer. The result are as expected. These two methods are the fastest. On Chrome and Firefox the `typeof`version is the fastest. On Internet Explorer the `instanceof` version was the fastest. But the difference in speed between these two methods were minor. Personally I'd still go with the `instanceof` method if I could because it's cleaner.

Comment: Note: I think this might be brittle in iframe situations - see the [MDC Doc Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/Instanceof_Operator#instanceof_and_multiple_scopes_%28e.g._frames_or_windows%29)

Comment: If generalized to a function, it would also need a check to ensure that `test` is not undefined, as `undefinedVariable instanceof Object` throws an exception.

Comment: partially correct. this test works when you do this: `var test = undefined;` It does however throw an exception when test is not declared. But that is a programming error so an exception is desired. Don't anticipate on programming errors if you want to find bugs!

Answer (score 7):

Just another short option:

```
function isPrimitive(value) {
  return Object(value) !== value;
}
```

How does it works:

If the `value` is a primitive value that is *convertible to object*, such as a `Number`, `String` or a `Boolean`, the strict equality operator will return true, since the [`Object` constructor called as a function](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.2.1), will convert the value to a "wrapped object":

```
typeof 5;         // "number"
typeof Object(5); // "object", a wrapped primitive
5 === Object(5);  // false
```

If the value is a primitive not convertible to Object, such as `null` or `undefined`, the Object constructor will create a new empty object, returning true.

The last case, if `value` holds a reference to an object, the `Object` constructor will do nothing, and the strict equality operator will return `false`.

Comment: +1 seems to work well - the wording around strict equality operator is a little confusing, should that be inequality?

Comment: +1 simple. Agreed with @jball though, just change the function to `isMutable` and use `===`.

Comment: +1 for out of the box thinking. I don't like the fact though that you are creating an extra object. This seems a downside to me in terms of performance.

Answer (score 2):

```
isMutable = function (test) {
     return test !== null && (typeof test == 'object' || typeof test == 'function');
}
```

Comment: This was my idea, except I just check for `test` instead of `test !== null`, e.g. `return test && (typeof test == 'object' || typeof test == 'function');`

Comment: @galambalazs the point is that `test` will evaluate to false if it is `null` or `undefined`, and then the `typeof` checks will handle the rest of the cases.

Answer (score 1):

Nice and short, just for fun (no `&&` or `||`s):

```
function isMutable(o) {
   return /(object)|(function)/.test(typeof(o||0));
}
```

Comment: Slower, as expected (http://jsperf.com/checking-mutability/2), but eye candy to me :P

Comment: Sure, this code creates a RegExp object every time you call it (well, it might, in most engines). BTW, I see a `||` there ;)

Comment: @Pumbaa80 ah you're right, how did I miss that. Interesting though ... the main performance hit wasn't in creating the regexp object but doing the `.test()`,at least on chrome

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you `try` if you're not sure?

Comment: @euphoria83, I'm pretty sure that galambalazs is recommending a `try catch` block.

Comment: oh yeah. I missed that he made `try' into a code fragment. Yet, that is not the generic solution to the question of how to detect if an object is immutable.

Comment: try is as generic as you can get... Also you save yourself from possible edge cases or incostencies.